# Nagios + MK Livestatus + port

Tags: python, iptables, nagios

I have already installed nagios and mk live status, nagios is working correctly and Im trying test mklive status with this command:

```
nc -v 127.0.0.1 6557 < nagios_query_file
```

nagios_query_file has that content:

```
GET hosts
Filter: name ~~ root
Filter: state = 0
OutputFormat: python
```

the output is:

```
nc: connect to 127.0.0.1 port 6557 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your port is not opened.
Just make sure you have configured Livestatus on xinetd.

- Install **xinetd**
- Create **/etc/xinetd.d/livestatus** with something like:

_

```
service livestatus
{
        type            = UNLISTED
        port            = 6557
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        wait            = no
        cps             = 100 3
        instances       = 500
        per_source      = 250
        flags           = NODELAY
        user            = nagios
        server          = /usr/bin/unixcat
        server_args     = /var/lib/nagios/rw/live
#       only_from       = 127.0.0.1 192.168.0.0
        disable         = no
}
```

See [Remote access to Livestatus via SSH or xinetd](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_livestatus.html#H1:Remote%20access%20to%20Livestatus%20via%20SSH%20or%20xinetd) for a detailed example

- Restart **xinetd** service

Then your example should work.

But that's only if you want to open your livestatus socket through the network (to have on one interface the results of several distributed nagios cores, for instance).

If you just want to test it locally, try with:

> echo "GET hosts" | unixcat /var/lib/nagios/rw/live

where */var/lib/nagios/rw/live* isyour livestatus socket